# Get items list count dynamically according to the filtering result

Tags: list, vue.js, count, quasar

My app displays the total posts count, initially according to the server's response.

However, these posts can be filtered and I need to get the post count dynamically according to the filtering result.

```
inputFilter:function() {
   var vm = this;
   return vm.posts.filter((post) => {
        var vmPosts = post.title.match(searchValue);
        var countFilteredPostsDinammicaly = vmPosts.count(); //??????
        return vmPosts;
   });
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You want the length of `posts` or you want the count of `post.title` dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a `computed` property which will return you a filtered array on basis of the query/filters applied.

Another `computed` property will return you the length of the filtered array i.e filtered post count to show on the DOM.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
   posts: [
    { title: 'apple is best fruit' },
    { title: 'orange is 2020 best fruit' },
    { title: 'apples are sweeter than oranges in 2020' }
   ],
   query: ''
  },
  
  computed: {
   getFilteredPosts () {
    return this.posts.filter(post => post.title.includes(this.query))
   },
   getFilteredPostsCount () {
    return this.getFilteredPosts.length
   }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
 
 <input placeholder="search for `apple`" v-model="query"/>
 <br/><br/>
 
 Filtered posts count: {{ getFilteredPostsCount }}
 <br/><br/>
 
 Filtered posts:
 <li v-for="(post, i) in getFilteredPosts" :key="i">
  {{ post.title }}
 </li>
 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Shivam Singh. Your solution was precisely what I was looking for. Thanks again.